# Comparing objects before and after update retrieved by LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQtoSQL and I need to compare object before and after update.

In the example below `Student` 'before' and `Student` 'curStudent' are the same, because they was retrieved by the same query.

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   Student before = db.Student.Where(q=>q.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
   Student curStudent = db.Student.Where(q=>q.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
   curStudent.Name = "NewName";
   db.SubmitChanges();
}

if(before.Name != curStudent.Name) // this condition will never be true
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to validate that the name change worked or are you really needing two separate instances?

Comment: I want to create a log system, to track the changes. In order to do that, I need to compare object before and after update.

Comment: You might look at [`GetChangeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The context will only keep one object per key value, so one way would be to use two separate contexts:

```
Student before;
using(DataContext db1 = new DataContext())
{
   before = db.Student.Where(q=>q.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
}

Student curStudent;
using(DataContext db2 = new DataContext())
{
   curStudent = db.Student.Where(q=>q.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
   curStudent.Name = "NewName";
   db.SubmitChanges();
}

if(before.Name != curStudent.Name) 
{
    //do something
}
```

Or if you're just interested in the name change, keep the previous value:

```
string before;

using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   Student curStudent = db.Student.Where(q=>q.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
   before = curStudent.Name;   // cache the name
   curStudent.Name = "NewName";
   db.SubmitChanges();
}

if(before != curStudent.Name) 
{
    //do something
}
```